# Reject an already accepted appointment?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, appointments

I have accepted an appointment thru outlook, later due to another more important arrangement I have to reject the already accepted appointment.

Is there any easy way to retrieve the invitation and reject it?

Comment: Off topic, but low hanging fruit, so: open it from your calendar and click on "Decline".

Comment: I wonder if this person has a SuperUser account. He may not see these comments and answers.

Answer (score 1):

Open the appointment. The "Accept" and "Decline" buttons will be visible. Click "Decline".

Comment: Aaaaargh. I'm looking for the exact opposite of this: How to accept a rejected appointment.

(But google don't know the difference between X to Y and Y to X)

Comment: I don't see any accept/reject button in outlook even opening the meeting already accepted